# Matlab Syntax and Python Syntax

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, matrix

I am trying to rewrite matlab code in Python. Everything was good so far, but this last equation is not coming together no matter what I do. I'm guessing it is just my poor understanding of matlab syntax. So here is the matlab equation (`Un(100, 1), a(100,1), X_basis(100,100)`):

```matlab
uN=uN+(a(i)*X_basis(:,i));
```

Every numpy array has been "translated" and the values match, except `uN`.
That is what I tried to do in Python:

```py
for i in range(1, N+1):
    uN[i] = (a[i] * X_basis[:][i])
```

and I tried the `uN = uN + ...` version, and still, the results don't match (at all).
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you should describe in detail what the matlab code does and provide examples of input/output

Comment: You cannot use `:` to refer to all indexes of a list in Python

Comment: the problem is that `:` has a different meaning in Python. To refer to all indexes in the list you have to iterate with a `for` cycle for instance

Comment: `X _basis[:,i]` is the correct way to select the `i` column.

Comment: @NicoCaldo, for `numpy` arrays, the use of `:` is similar to MATLAB,   However the OP is using it in a list type indexing where it does nothing useful.

Comment: You need to be more explicit about the numpy array shapes, and what you expect to happen.  A [mcve] will help.

Answer (score 1):

I got it

```py
for i in range(1, N+1):
    uNtemp[i] = np.transpose(X_basis)[:][i] * float(a[i])

for i in range(1, M+1):
    uN[i] = np.sum(np.transpose(uNtemp)[i])
```

It turns out Matlab basically does this piece of code. Thank you all for your comments!